# How to get ant JUnit result in user defined xml file name?

Tags: ant, junit4

How to get ant JUnit result in user defined xml file name?
Junit (ant task) by default creates TEST-testcasename.xml for results, is there a way to change this xml file name? I am running same testcase multiple times for different browsers and currently the result for one browser is being overwritten by another browser's result.

Here is my code:

```
<target name="junit1">
<junit fork="true" forkmode="once" haltonfailure="false" logfailedtests="true">
<classpath refid="classpath.project"/>
<formatter type="xml"/>
<jvmarg value="-Dbrowser=${browser}"/>
<batchtest todir="${dir.report}">
    <fileset dir="${dir.src}">
        <include name="${testcase}"/>
    </fileset>
</batchtest>
</junit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a different output directory for each browser, or copy the output directory to another one when tests are finished?

```
<batchtest todir="${dir.report}/${browser}">
```

If you need all the files to be in the same directory, rename (or copy) them after each batch using the `move` (or `copy`) task with a glob mapper :

```
<mapper type="glob" from="TEST*.xml" to="${browser}-TEST*.xml"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I could use a different output directory for each browser but then I would run into problems while running <junitreport>. I need a summary of test results for all browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to use mapper to get different result xml files for each browser. But I am not able to get a proper report generated using junitreport, It does list results for all browsers but testcase name is duplicated for each browser, So just by looking at the summary report, there is no way to tell which result is for which browser.

Comment: I looked at editing junit-frames.xsl file, so that I could extract the browser name from the results xml file. It looks like I need tp navigate the following in the result xml file:                                                             <testsuite errors="0" failures="0" hostname="abc" name="ICT_Din_Dup" tests="1" time="145.979" timestamp="2011-10-31T16:42:51">
  <properties>
    <property name="browser" value="firefox" />                                                                   I don't know how to access it in the junit-frame.xsl file.

Comment: Don't know either, sorry. I suck at XSL.

Answer (score 1):

Use the extension attribute of the formatter element

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

```
<formatter type="xml" extension="${browser}.xml"/>
```

This will append the browser name to the end of each output file